# Scrapy callback after redirect

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a very basic scrapy spider, which grabs urls from the file and then downloads them. The only problem is that some of them got redirected to a slightly modified url within same domain. I want to get them in my callback function using *response.meta*, and it works on a normal urls, but then url is redirected callback doesn't seem to get called. How can I fix it?
Here's my code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy import Request
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302]
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.exmaple.net/"]) 
    f = open("C:\\python27\\1a.csv",'r')
    url = 'http://www.exmaple.net/Query?indx='
    start_urls = [url+row for row in f.readlines()]
    def parse(self, response):
            print response.meta.get('redirect_urls', [response.url])
            print response.status 
            print (response.headers.get('Location'))
```

I've also tried something like that:

```
def parse(self, response):
         return Request(response.url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list':     [302]}, callback=self.parse_my_url)
def parse_my_url(self, response):
        print response.status 
        print (response.headers.get('Location'))
```

And it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default scrapy requests are redirected, although if you don't want to redirect you can do like this, use **start_requests** method and add flags in request meta.

```
    def start_requests(self):
        requests =[(Request(self.url+u, meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [302],
                               'dont_redirect': True},         
                    callback=self.parse)) for u in self.start_urls]
        return requests
```

Comment: No, I need to get the redirected urls, they are good in this case.

Comment: you can get them from callback function, there must be **moved on link** or you can get url from location under headers